# SQL Merge the row into new column

Tags: sql, string

I have a table named `Addresses`.

The columns are:

```
Property | Road | Town | Borough | District | Postcode
```

There is no data in `Property` as of yet as I will update it manually later. The rest of the columns does hold data though.

However I need to merge `Road, Town, Borough, District` and `Postcode` into a new column named `Full Address`.

So for example

```
Property |    Road     |     Town     |  Borough  |  District  | Postcode | Full Address
  NULL     London Road      London       Enfield      North      EN16 5FD   NULL, London Road, London, Enfield, North, EN16 5FD
```

If you can see the "Full Address" column has taken everything from the same row and added it into the row itself.

How would I be able to do this within SQL?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Do not store values calculated from other column. Create a view instead. (Or have a computed column.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want string concatenation. Many databases support `concat_ws()`:

```
update mytable
set full_address = concat_ws(', ', 
    property,
    road,
    town,
    borough,
    district,
    postcode
);
```

The behavior on `concat_ws()` as regard to `null` values varies across databases. Some will return a `null` value if any value in the list is `null`; in that case, you might want to surround `null`able columns in the list with `coalesce()`, as in `coalesce(property, '')`.

If your database does not support `group_concat()`, then use the regular string concatenation operator; in standard SQL, that's `||`:

```
    property    || ', '
    || road     || ', '
    || town     || ', '
    || borough  || ', '
    || district || ', '
    || postcode
```

Finally: it is not necessarily a good idea to store this *derived* information. Instead, you can use a computed column or a view:

```
create view myview as
select t.*,
    concat_ws(', ', 
        property,
        road,
        town,
        borough,
        district,
        postcode
    ) as full_address
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 1):

GMB has already answered a question by using `concat_ws()` function, but you can also do it using `CONCAT()` function as below.

```
SELECT 
        Road, 
        Town, 
        Borough, 
        District,
        CONCAT(Road,' ', Town,' ', Borough,' ', District) as Full_Address
    FROM mytable
```

Comment: Perfect! I mixed both yours and GMB codes together as I couldn't use concat_ws and it worked perfectly :)